# Applicative Laws for the ((->) r) type

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to check that the Applicative laws hold for the function type `((->) r)`, and here's what I have so far:

```
-- Identiy
pure (id) <*> v = v 
-- Starting with the LHS
pure (id) <*> v
const id <*> v
(\x -> const id x (g x))
(\x -> id (g x))
(\x -> g x)
g x
v


-- Homomorphism
pure f <*> pure x = pure (f x)
-- Starting with the LHS
pure f <*> pure x
const f <*> const x
(\y -> const f y (const x y))
(\y -> f (x))
(\_ -> f x)
pure (f x)
```

Did I perform the steps for the first two laws correctly?

I'm struggling with the interchange & composition laws. For interchange, so far I have the following:

```
-- Interchange
u <*> pure y = pure ($y) <*> u
-- Starting with the LHS
u <*> pure y
u <*> const y
(\x -> g x (const y x))
(\x -> g x y)
-- I'm not sure how to proceed beyond this point.
```

I would appreciate any help for the steps to verify the Interchange & Composition applicative laws for the `((->) r)` type. For reference, the Composition applicative law is as follows:

```
pure (.) <*> u <*> v <*> w = u <*> (v <*> w)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think in your "Identity" proof, you should replace `g` with `v` everywhere (otherwise what is `g` and where did it come from?). Similarly, in your "Interchange" proof, things look okay so far, but the `g` that magically appears should just be `u`. To continue that proof, you could start reducing the RHS and verify that it also produces `\x -> u x y`.

Composition is more of the same: plug in the definitions of `pure` and `(<*>)` on both sides, then start calculating on both sides. You'll soon come to some bare lambdas that will be easy to prove equivalent.

Comment: Thank you for the tips. When I used g in place of u & v, it made sense to my head, but now I cannot think why I chose to do so. Your suggestion of reducing LHS and RHS independently certainly helped, and I was able to solve the Interchange equation. As a Haskell beginner, I will need to spend some time with the Composition lambdas before I'm done.

Comment: I couldn't post my attempt for the Composition law here, as I couldn't format the code correctly. Instead, I have posted a new follow-up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34538754/proving-composition-applicative-law-for-r-type