# Proving Composition Applicative law for ((->) r) type

Tags: haskell

The Composition Applicative Law is as follows:

```
pure (.) <*> u <*> v <*> w = u <*> (v <*> w)
```

Here's my attempt at proving the Composition law for the `((->) r)` type:

RHS:

```
u <*> (v <*> w)
u <*> ( \y -> v y (w y) )
\x -> u x ( (\y -> v y (w y)) x )
\x -> u x ( v x (w x)) -- (A)
```

LHS:

```
pure (.) <*> u <*> v <*> w
const (.) <*> u <*> v <*> w
(\f -> const (.) f (u f)) <*> v <*> w
(\f -> (.) (u f)) <*> v <*> w
(\g -> (\f -> (.) (u f)) g (v g)) <*> w
\x -> (\g -> (\f -> (.) (u f)) g (v g)) x (w x)
-- Expanding labmda by applying to x
\x -> ((\f -> (.) (u f)) x (v x)) (w x)
\x -> (( (.) (u x)) (v x)) (w x)

\x -> ((u x) . (v x)) (w x) -- (B)
```

I don't think (A) & (B) are equivalent, so where did I make a mistake? I would appreciate any help or suggestions.

Comment: This question is related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33829415/applicative-laws-for-the-r-type. However, I couldn't post the code in this question directly as a comment, so I decided to add a new follow-up question instead

Comment: Substitute in the definition `(f . g) x = f (g x)` for the composition in the last line of the LHS... and you're done!

Comment: Le sigh. Missed something really simple. Could you post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: For a friendlier presentation of the `Applicative` laws, see [this blog post](http://blog.ezyang.com/2012/08/applicative-functors/) by Edward Yang. Also, you might consider jumping ahead and proving the monad laws instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there. You just need to use the definition of `(.)`, which is

```
(f . g) x = f (g x)
```

After substituting that definition in the last line of your LHS calculation, you should have two obviously equal lambdas.